# is the broadcast receiver registered via manifest is automatically unregister on app close?

Tags: android

I have been registering a broadcast receiver via manifest. On close of application, is this broadcast receiver automatically unregistered or do we have to unregister it manually? If we don't unregister it manually, will it cause memory leak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android `BroadcastReceiver` declared in the manifest are not automatically unregistered. Those can be triggered even when the app is not running (that is the expected behavior too). When a `BroadcastReceiver` is triggered, the `onReceive` callback method is called. The broadcast is only active during the execution of the `onReceive` method. Once the method is returned, the receiver is considered as inactive. So, if you want to declare a `BroadcastReceiver` which can be triggered always (even when the app is not running), you declare it in the manifest. And you don't have to worry about its lifecycle.

However, if you want to declare a broadcast which will receive broadcast only during a certain amount of time (e.g., when app is running or when an activity is running), then it is better to register the broadcast when needed and unregister it when the work is done. For example, if you want to receive a broadcast only when an activity is running, then you can register in in the `onCreate` method and unregister it in the `onDestroy` method.